# How Can I Manipulate a page behind a login using Sitecore's FXM?

Tags: sitecore8, sitecore-fxm

I'm trying to allow my site editors to manipulate a page that is behind a login, using Sitecore's FXM tool. However I have not been able to navigate to those pages inside the FXM tool. I can bring up the logon on page inside FXM but the site either does not properly submit the logon data or it doesn't accept the prerequisite cookie needed to be logged on.

My temporary workaround is that the site whose content needs to be updated will allow access to computers from the Sitecore IP address, however I would like to know if there is a way to do this without having to supplement user logons with IP sniffing.